# Запуск второй формы в qt

Tags: qt

Как запустить вторую форму в Qt по нажатию на кнопку на первой форме?

Comment: В обработчике клика первой форм создавайте объект второй формы (не указывая родителя) и все будет хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляешь в public первой формы  объект класса второй формы. 
Из слота кнопки в первой форме вызываешь метод show() этого обяъекта.